# Bootstrap-UI custom popover trigger not working

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, eventtrigger

I want to display a popover, replacing the default browser validation pop-ups.
Since UI only knows click, focus and mouseenter as default trigger [to open popovers](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover), i added a custom trigger to the triggermap ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29871546/2107372)).

```
 angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap'])  
     .config(['$tooltipProvider', function($tooltipProvider){
     $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({'customEvent': 'customEvent'}); }]);
```

Which seems to work, as the triggermap does grow, and at some point emits even the new trigger. 
Sadly the intended popover never appears and the eval-function before is not called (so no logic or style issue, which would be applied later) when fireing a 'customEvent':

```
<input id="searchBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="..." value="..." popover="test here" popover-placement="bottom" popover-trigger="customEvent">
```

Using a default trigger like 'click' works perfectly.

```
$('#searchBtn').trigger('click');
```

(Alas, using one of the default triggers would be the last resort for me, since it entails some unwanted things...)
Any suggestions ? (using bootstrap-ui 0.13.4)

Comment: What events do you want to trigger the popover?  Version 0.4.x now exposes the isOpen property so you could use that instead.

Comment: thats what I came up with as well in the end... thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The 0.13.4 release introduced the `*-is-open` attribute which allows you to programmatically control when the tooltip/popover is open.  See [the docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) for more info.

If you want to use custom triggers, you need to actually trigger `customEvent` manually since the browser can't do so for you (since it's not a native event).

Comment: thats what i did: $('#searchBtn').trigger('customEvent'); which is not working... prompting me to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: Without seeing a minimal, working plunker that demonstrates the issue, I cannot comment as to why what you did didn't work.